# Medir area de un rectángulo en C utilizando punteros y arrays

Tags: c, array, punteros

Básicamente estoy buscando hacer que esta función deje en un array ordenado el área de cada rectángulo.

Código:

```
int main(){
printf("Programa RECTANGULOS!\n");
int cantidad = 3; //Cantidad 3 porque el 0 cuenta
float  alto[]={ 1, 3, 5.5,  8};
float ancho[]={25,50,75.9,100};
float area[cantidad];
sacarArea(&cantidad, &ancho, &alto, &area);
return 0;}
```

... y la función es:

```
void sacarArea(int *cantidad, float *ancho[], float *alto[], float *area[]){

int i;
float auxancho,auxalto;
for(i = 0; i<=*cantidad; i++){

    auxancho=ancho[i];
    auxalto = alto[i];

    *area[i] = (auxancho * auxalto)/2;

} }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Ya te he puesto una solución funciona, ahora te voy a explicar el motivo por el que la definición que haces de los parámetros no es correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene varias deficiencias que te iré enumerando poco a poco.

Esta es una versión de tu programa funcional:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sacarArea(
    int cantidad,
    float ancho[],
    float alto[],
    float area[]
) {
    int i;
    float auxancho, auxalto;
    for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        auxancho = ancho[i];
        auxalto = alto[i];
        area[i] = (auxancho * auxalto) / 2;
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, cantidad = 4; /* Cantidad es 4 porque son 4 elementos, del 0 al 3 */
    float alto[] = { 1, 3, 5.5, 8 };
    float ancho[] = { 25, 50, 75.9, 100 };
    float area[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    printf("Programa RECTANGULOS!\n");
    sacarArea(cantidad, ancho, alto, area);
    for (i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        printf("Area %d: %f\n", i, area[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Este es el resultado de la compilación y ejecución:

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic areas.c -o areas && valgrind ./areas
==2361== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2361== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2361== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2361== Command: ./areas
==2361== 
Programa RECTANGULOS!
Area 0: 12.500000
Area 1: 75.000000
Area 2: 208.725006
Area 3: 400.000000
==2361== 
==2361== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2361==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2361==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==2361== 
==2361== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2361== 
==2361== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2361== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Para comenzar he cambiado la definición de la función porque no vamos a modificar la zona de memoria donde se almacena el array de entrada ni de salida:

```
void sacarArea(
    int cantidad,
    float ancho[],
    float alto[],
    float area[]
);
```

Además, y lo más importante, es que `float *ancho[]` es equivalente a `float **ancho` que significa "puntero a un puntero que apunta a un dato de tipo `float`", por lo que `*ancho[i]` se traduce como "obtén el i-ésimo puntero a `float`" y no "obtén el i-ésimo elemento `float`".

Por lo que es sinónimo que declarar (las dos formas serían idénticas):

```
void sacarArea(
    int cantidad,
    float *ancho,
    float *alto,
    float *area
);
```

De esta manera el acceso a los datos es mucho más sencillo:

```
auxancho = ancho[i];
auxalto = alto[i];
area[i] = (auxancho * auxalto) / 2;
```

Y, por último, he cambiado la definición de tu variable `cantidad` ya que son 4 elementos y no 3 los que tienes en el array, por lo que debes recorrerlo desde el elemento 0 hasta el 4:

```
int main() {
    int i, cantidad = 4; /* Cantidad es 4 porque son 4 elementos, del 0 al 3 */
```

Y, en el bucle de la función:

```
for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Cantidad no haría falta pasarlo por referencia por el mismo motivo.

---

**Solución alternativa con estructuras**

Para evitar problemas derivados de matrices de tamaños diferentes y para mejorar la lectura del código, podrías usar estructuras de datos para almacenar el alto, ancho y área de cada triángulo en un único elemento:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    float ancho, alto, area;
} t_triangulo;

void sacarArea(
  int cantidad,
  t_triangulo triangulos[]
) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    triangulos[i].area = (triangulos[i].ancho * triangulos[i].alto) / 2;
  }
}

int main() {
  /* ¡OJO! Esta forma de definir estructuras requiere estándar C99 */
  /*t_triangulo triangulos[] = {
    { .alto = 1, .ancho = 25, .area = 0 },
    { .alto = 3, .ancho = 50, .area = 0 },
    { .alto = 5.5, .ancho = 75.9, .area = 0 },
    { .alto = 8, .ancho = 100, .area = 0 }
  };*/
  /* Si tu compilador no soporta el estándar C99 entonces usa: */
  t_triangulo triangulos[] = {
    { 1, 25, 0 },
    { 3, 50, 0 },
    { 5.5, 75.9, 0 },
    { 8, 100, 0 }
  };
  /* Cantidad es 4 porque son 4 elementos, del 0 al 3 */
  int i, cantidad = 4;
  /* También puedes definir "cantidad" como:
       tamaño de todos los datos / tamaño de un único dato: */
  /*int cantidad = sizeof(triangulos) / sizeof(t_triangulo);*/

  printf("Programa RECTANGULOS!\n");
  sacarArea(cantidad, triangulos);

  for (i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    printf("Area nº %d (%.1f, %.1f): %.1f\n",
      i, triangulos[i].ancho, triangulos[i].alto, triangulos[i].area
    );
  }
  return 0;
}
```